# No network devices available eventhough I can online

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have access to the internet...

But I couldn't see or choose or add any wifi connection

Cause it shows no network devices available under my network icon

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:e3:47:23:39:2e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:19 memory:b3400000-b3403fff



00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Run `sudo service network-manager restart`. If this does not help, [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Comment: So, you are connected to something but it does not show up, right ? It's a possibility that the network to which you are connected has hidden `essid`. Run `nmcli dev list` if you are using 14.04 or `nmcli dev show` on 15.04, and it should tell you what you're connected to. A lot of places use common essids like, attwifi or xfinitywifi, so it's quite possible you automatically connected to a hotspot with such essid

Comment: @Serg There is nothing showing up when I run nmcli dev list or nmcli dev wifi...

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of the following file through terminal command :

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

It should be something like :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

unless you have some other services running related to networking like hotspot or any other.

Comment: Yes...it is...
> # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Is there anything else in the file ?
What is the content of the file :
 /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Comment: Nothing else in the file...My /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf contains [main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=true

Comment: Try this, I'm not sure, it may or may not work :

[keyfile]

unmanaged-devices=mac:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Add these two lines after dnsmasq in new line  and change MAC according to your wireless device which you can easily find out by 'ifconfig' command
And, put [keyfile] and rest stuff in different lines